# Monitor backlight stays on even in sleep

Tags: macbook-pro

External monitor stays on for most of the time laptop is in sleep. M2 MacBook Air 2022 macOS Sonoma, connected using USB-C Thunderbolt my LG monitor was fine until recently. When I leave my desk and MacBook in clamshell mode, (which occurs even when the laptop is open) the monitor backlight turns on for anywhere between 2 to 10 minutes or more at a time, it's very annoying at this point,

Things I've tried:

- Putting the Mac on airplane mode
- Disconnecting all appliances

Nothing worked, but if I unplugged the Thunderbolt, then the display would act normal.

Comment: Same problem as what? I fixed my problem by connecting the monitor directly to the MacBook using HDMI, instead of using the USB hub and DisplayPort.

Comment: @Barmar my monitor has a built in dock, I connected to the thunderbolt port, has pass through charging as well, M2 Air don't got any other ports, also the monitor was working fine before an update, this issue didn't exist before, now it does

Comment: It would depend on your Power settings, run `pmset -g` in terminal to see them

Comment: @Ruskes Excuse my formatting, im new to stack exchange.

pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
 SleepDisabled  0
Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             1
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                5 (sleep prevented by sharingd, useractivityd, powerd)
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 tcpkeepalive         1
 lowpowermode         0
 womp                 1